# Understanding an answer about joint distribution of dependent random variables

Tags: probability

Here is a [question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478035/discovering-the-joint-distribution-for-two-dependent-random-variables) about finding the joint distribution of $X_1,X_2$ where $X_1+X_2=Y$ and distributions of $X_1,X_2,Y$ are known.

In the answer, there is an example where $X_1\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ and $X_2\in \{0,1,\ldots,m\}$. Then the answer says the distributions of $X_1,X_2,X_1+X_2,(X_1,X_2)$ depend on $n,m,n+m,nm+n+m$ parameters respectively.

> I'm trying to understand what the writer means by "parameters".

I see that $X_1$ has a support of $n+1$ points, $X_2$ has a support of $m+1$ points and hence $(X_1,X_2)$ has a support of $(n+1)(m+1)=nm+n+m+1$ points.

1. But I don't understand the connection between size of the support set and "parameters".
2. I also don't understand why $X_1+X_2$ has $n+m$ parameters.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the term *parameter* can be used to reference a number of quantities that are used to determine a distribution. For example, a normal distribution depends on two parameters: the population mean and the population variance. For example, see the [Wikipedia article on normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

In this case of finite sets, the pdf on a set consisting of $n+1$ elements depends on the pdf values at $n$ of those elements (since the sum of the pdf values over all $n+1$ elements must be $1$). This seems to me to be what the author of that post meant by parameters. To be a bit more explicit, suppose we are defining a probability distribution on a the set $\{ 0,1,2,3 \}$. Once we define the probability $P(X = j)$ for $0 \leq j \leq 2$, the value of $P(X=3)$ is decided. So the distribution on $\{ 0,1,2,3 \}$ is determined uniquely by the values at $3$ elements.

Now, for $X_1 + X_2$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ have $n$ and $m$ parameters, respectively, defining values for both $X_1$ and $X_2$ depends on $n+m$ values; $n$ to determine the distribution on $X_1$ and $m$ to determine the distribution on $X_2$. Alternatively, $X_1 + X_2$ takes on values in $\{0,1,2,\ldots, n+m\}$, which is a set of $n+m+1$ elements, so the number of parameters is $n+m$.

To compare against $(X_1,X_2)$, as you've noted, $(X_1,X_2)$ takes values that are ordered pairs from a set of size $nm+n+m+1$ elements, so any distribution on $(X_1,X_2)$ relies on $nm+n+m$ values. Unlike the case when we are considering $X_1 + X_2$, the pdf can take on different values at $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your answer. Let me ask a question about this example: $X$ is a uniform distribution on $[0,1,2,\ldots,n]$. Conditional on $X$ is uniform, $X$ is not a $n$ parameter distribution, right?

Comment: Am I correct in saying that a general probability distribution on $[0,1,\ldots,n]$ is a $n-$parameter distribution. But if we know $X$ is uniform on $[0,1,\ldots,n]$, then $X$ is not a $n$ parameter distribution?

Comment: @Garfield correct. If you know the distribution has to be uniform, then it is a 1 parameter distribution - it depends only on the cardinality of the set.